# Solidity Internal exception in StandardCompiler

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

This is the source code

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract myContract{
    string value;

    constructor() public {
        value = "myValue";
    }

    function get() public view returns(string memory){
        return value;
    }

    function set(string memory _value) public{
        value = _value;
    }
}
```

Selected Compiler on Remix IDE is `0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62`
Selected Environment is `Javascript VM`

When I compile the command I get this error

```
Internal exception in StandardCompiler::compileInternal: /root/project/libevmasm/ExpressionClasses.cpp(187): Throw in function ExpressionClasses::Id dev::eth::ExpressionClasses::tryToSimplify(const dev::eth::ExpressionClasses::Expression &)
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<dev::eth::OptimizerException>
std::exception::what: Rule list not properly initialized.
[dev::tag_comment*] = Rule list not properly initial
```

However this error does not pop up for same source code if I select the compiler as `0.5.11`

Other users are saying that they are getting this error on pre `0.5.3` compilers.

Comment: I can compile with 0.5.1 using Remix and no errors are reported.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in a certain version of the compiler - it does not work properly if the javascript runtime environment does not provide enough stack space or memory. It should work with the most recent compilers.
Check this [thread](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/issues/1644) for more info